# HLSL shaders and accessing current location the GPU is at in the index buffer

Tags: xna, hlsl

My question is very basic.

Is there an HLSL shader instruction or any way within shader code to access the current location that the GPU is up to within the array of the index buffer? I am using XNA Game Studio 4.0 which via the GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives() method passes VertexBuffers and IndexBuffers to the graphics pipeline per mesh.  I know the GPU iterates through the IndexBuffer internally but I was hoping it was possible to ascertain which entry within the IndexBuffer that the GPU was currently at:

To express what I mean in psuedocode:
IndexBuffer[i], where I want to know the value of i that the GPU is currently processing.

The reason for this is I want to know which polygon is currently being rendered and it's not possible to tell simply by knowing the vertex because a single vertex is always shared between multiple polygons.

Is my question clear and can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Vertex Shader you process a vertex only, so you can't know which primitive is actually rendered (since it's actually not assembled yet). in DirectX 10+ you can know the vertex id (SV_VertexID input semantic), but it will still not be polygon based. Out of interest what usage would you want to do for this, might help on more customized answer for it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I designed a way of assigning uv coordinates to models but it's polygon based. I achieved this simply by creating a "textureIndexBuffer" which is insynch with the IndexBuffer. I.e., indexBuffer[i] corresponds to textureIndexBuffer[i]. The textureIndexBuffer is simply an array of a construct:

Comment: mm i guess best way in this case it to split vertices, since vertices are shared they will share uvs. Only other way you could do this would be with geometry shaders, and afaik you can't access this in xna, otherwise if you need 2 uvs for same vertex then you need to have 2 vertices.

Comment: Hmmm, ok. I'll have to brainstorm on this new info. Appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: don't share vertices, and include polygon ID's as a vertex attribute.

Fancier answers might be possible if you know special facts about the tessellation (say, it's a sphere, or the UVs are laid out in a grid, etc -- so the placement of polys is predictable).